# Correctly convert SASS Interpolation to LESS

Tags: css, sass, less

Can't convert SASS peace of code to LESS, it gives me "Unrecognized input" on line with 
**&:@{pseudo} {**

SASS Code:

```
@mixin mm_border( $border, $pseudo, $size, $pos1, $pos2 ) {
    &:#{$pseudo} {
        ...
    }
}
```

LESS Code:

```
.mm_border( @border, @pseudo, @size, @pos1, @pos2 ) {
    &:@{pseudo} {
    ...
    }
}
```

And I have error on line &:@{pseudo} {

And as I know only difference from SASS it that #{ $var } on SASS is @{ var } on LESS, so where could be problem ?

My Less compiler version is 1.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `:` in `&:@{pseudo}` presumably because it is trying to assign `@{pseudo}` to a variable and it can't.

The below is a hack to overcome it. Not the only solution (and most probably not the best either) but this is one way you can use.

**Code:**

```
.mm_border( @border, @pseudo, @size, @pos1, @pos2 ) {
  @temp: ~":"; 
  &@{temp}@{pseudo} {
        border: @size @border #abc;
    }
}
.mm{
  .mm_border(solid,after,1px,1,2);
}
```

**Compiled Output:** (In LESS 1.6.0 but that shouldn't be a problem)

```
.mm:after {
  border: 1px solid #aabbcc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I asked same question on less.js github issues page. Here is link for that, if someone needs more info https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2091#issuecomment-48024883